# How can I save a model with weights to a single protobuf file with Tensorflow Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to get a model to export in the format produced by `tf.saved_model.save` which is a large .pb containing the whole model and the weights.

I have

```
estimator.export_saved_model(
    export_dir_base=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'),
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn
)
```

for a Sagemaker script mode training script but it seems to output the protobuf format with a large variables folder and a small .pb file. How can I have it export a full model in .pb form?

This is running in script form on a Sagemaker training instance so I would like to avoid manual freeze_graph.py commands done locally if possible.

Comment: Hi @King Dedede, Kindly provide more details or screenshot regarding the files and if you could also provide a minimum reproducible code.

Comment: In `Tensorflow`, it is not possible to save the Model in a single protobuf file, either using `tf.saved_model.save` or using `tf.keras.models.save_model`. You can check this link, https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html. Thanks! Happy Learning!